# How can I secure a backend to my libgdx game without HTTPS?

Tags: https, libgdx

I would like to include some common multiplayer elements in my libgdx game. The first step is to have some sort of authentication with my web server. Unfortunately it looks like libgdx does not support HTTPS so how can I let my user login without a secure connection? The user could pretty easily look at the HTTP traffic and hack the game with some other HTTP client. Is there an easy answer or do I have to use platform specific implementations?

Comment: What makes you think that libgdx doesn't support HTTPS?

Comment: I don't see any mention of HTTPS in the wiki and there is only an HTTPRequest class

Comment: Provide an https:// URL and HTTPS will be used.

Comment: Oh, nice! I'll try that out.